# How do websites remember their users?

Tags: authentication, cookies, web-deployment

After logging in and validating the users login credential a website has to somehow map each request on the site to a logged in user. I only did user management with various framework so far and I have some question on how this is done. As I want to write a thin website which itself acts as a client to piece of software with its own user management I cannot just use a framework here.

As far as I can follow a website can do one of two things:

- use http authentication, which is a huge pain in the neck, as logging users out is unreliable and the UI is generally ugly;
- use cookies with some secret per user.

What I struggle to understand is the "Remember me" check boxes on login forms. Reading up on the mostly not very technical explanations those check boxes make the browser save a cookie. Where I come to the question:
Don't all form-based-login using websites store a cookie to identify a client? If not, how does the server match a request with those clients?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they all do. "Remember me" is saving settings for a user, not identifying the user. It's a cookie keeping them logged in or pre-inserting their user name into the form (depending on how its built.)

Comment: So checking the "Remember me" box only makes the cookie valid longer?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538226/how-does-the-remember-my-password-checkbox-work